# Вывод информации в два столбика

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Нужно вывести данные на экран в два столбика. Для наглядности картинка (первая картинка):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте UICollectionView, если приложение для iOS 6+

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!